# wpf begininvoke for updating ui

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

Hello i am working with c# wpf. now problem is threading. I cannot access other thread the UI elements and when i using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke I cannot control Window. The calculate take about 5min. I want update calculate state to UI progressbar and move windows my self. Who can help me. :)

```
public delegate void TrainDelegate();

private void btnTrain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new TrainDelegate(StartTrain));
}
```

in `StartTrain` function I called textbox.
like follow

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtbTrainPath.Text);
```

It works but block main window. they said `Begininvoke` is non-block calling.
Could you please help me? What should be changed here?

Comment: There is too less code to analyse where it goes wrong. You could add some more. like how you execute the calculate on the thread etc.

Comment: i used simplest dispatcher method

Comment: it would be better to get textbox content from Dispatcher.Invoke (if needed) and then start a thread with the text as parameter

Comment: major problem is mainwindow is blocking. i want to move main window while running this long calculation thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, then

```
private void btnTrain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myText = txtbTrainPath.Text;
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { StartTrain(myText); } );
}
```

Comment: <ProgressBar x:Name="prgbState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="51,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="453"/>

Comment: this is my progress bar i want to update this progress bar state in real time

Comment: in your delegate call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { prgbState.Value =+++ } );

Comment: if i use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke it will be block mainwindows again. am i right?

Comment: now i used above your code so it not block mainwindow. that BeginInvoke function said me non-block. but now really it blocking my mainwindows.

Comment: StartTrain() {  // loop ///code Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { prgbState.Value =+++ }; //code //endloop } - just put the update in the disp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141522/discussion-between-riguang-zheng-and-gcamel).

Comment: You probably shouldn't use the `StartNew` here.